# NOOBS multiboot - resize partitions

Tags: noobs, partition, multiboot

I just started playing with NOOBS and a question came to my mind. I installed Raspbian, OpenELEC and OSMC on the same SD.

The config didn't ask how I wanted to split the memory for the three OSs and now I wonder if I can give more space to one of those OSs ( OSMC namely )

Comment: Use parted/gparted for resizing partitions/filesystems you need.

Comment: When you say "memory" you do mean "space or capacity on the SD card"? After all it is not quite the same thing - I've just come from a question where the OP was asking about the memory split between the CPU and the GPU and your usage throw me for a moment! 8-)

Answer (score 1):

A way to resize the different partitions on the NOOBS sd card is to use a different sd card and reformat it with the sizes you wish (with limits) and copy the different filesystems in the partitions to the new sd card. As a guide see the procedures in [How can I backup my whole SD to an img file usable with Etcher to restore later?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66556/how-can-i-backup-my-whole-sd-to-an-img-file-usable-with-etcher-to-restore-later/66991#66991).

Answer (score 0):

The NOOBS image is designed to get new users up and running quickly to play with different OS environments but it is extremely limited has no built-in ability to resize partitions.  Once you have decided on a preferred OS, longer term, you really should consider migrated away from NOOBS and make a dedicated OS install for your preferred OS. NOOBS "wastes" a lot of space with the other OSes that you ultimately won't use.

As suggested by @nsilent22, I have had some success resizing partitions with *gparted* which I access using a Ubuntu virtual machine on my Windowz machine.

Comment: Or, of course, on a GNU/Linux machine directly - just make **very sure** you are editing the right device/partition...! 8-)

Comment: As above, gparted works great for this very purpose.
But, be careful not to delete partitions or reorganize them if you don't know how to change what needs to be changed else you can render it unbootable. Also, back it up prior to trying.
You can use the backup to boot to in order to change partitions on your primary.